# Does anyone know an alt code for ac/dc - Alternating Current (AC) Direct Current (DC)?

Tags: ac-dc

[image: AC/DC symbol]
I have been trying to find an alt code for the ac/dc symbol, but have not found one or a way to suggest it.

Comment: What is an alt code?

Comment: What do you mean by "one or a way to suggest it"?

Comment: I *think* OP means a way to type that symbol in unicode. For instance, on linux, press left control, shift and u, then type 2393*space* and "⎓" (DC Symbol) appears or 23e6 and  "⏦" (Sine wave) appears. But I cant find the symbol the OP is looking for. source of info: http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2393/index.htm

Comment: I think they might be referring to Microsoft Windows alt codes, which allow you to enter characters not on the keyboard using the alt key and typing a number. I think the number corresponds to a unicode code point, but I'm not sure. I don't think the symbol they want has a code point.

Comment: Isn't there an Alt code for an overbar? In which case, you would write ~ + ¯ = ̅~̅

Answer (score 4):

I am assuming that by "alt code" you mean Windows/IBM compatible Alt codes for character entry.

Because you did not include a character in your post, it is difficult to say which character you want. I do not believe that exact character exists in Unicode, and consequently you'll need a custom character set and font to use it. I'll list a couple that exist in Unicode that might come in handy, along with the Unicode code point and name:

⎓: U+2393 DIRECT CURRENT SYMBOL FORM TWO
⏦: U+23E6 AC CURRENT
∿: U+223F SINE WAVE

You can type Unicode code points by holding down the Alt key, pressing "+" and entering the hex value of the code point.

Answer (score 0):

Try Unicode 2242.

E.g., in Word, type: \$\small 2242\:alt\:x\$ and you get: ≂

Alternatively use (!):

[image]

Comment: Alt codes for windows. AC/DC image is a straight line with a squiggle under it. ALT 61 is an equal sign

Comment: Thank you so much. I got the AC/DC code by using Segoe UI Symbol and 2242 ≂